# How to force CMake not add major/minor version in shared library filename and soname?

Tags: android, cmake, clang, llvm

I'm compiling **libclang** with Cmake for Android (with Android NDK).

Here is the part of CMake configuration that configure filename and soname:

```
set_target_properties(libclang
    PROPERTIES
    VERSION ${LIBCLANG_LIBRARY_VERSION}
    DEFINE_SYMBOL _CINDEX_LIB_)
```

In different file:

```
set(LIBCLANG_LIBRARY_VERSION
    "${CLANG_VERSION_MAJOR}" CACHE STRING
    "Major version number that will be appended to the libclang library")
```

and

```
if(NOT DEFINED CLANG_VERSION_MAJOR)
  set(CLANG_VERSION_MAJOR ${LLVM_VERSION_MAJOR})
endif()
```

Since i compile llvm/clang of version "7.0.0" libclang filename and soname is `libclang.so.7`  which is not desired for Android.

```
~/llvm/build anton$ls -l lib/libclang.so
lrwxrwxrwx 1 anton anton 13 Nov 30 12:13 lib/libclang.so -> libclang.so.7
~/llvm/build anton$arm-linux-androideabi-readelf --dynamic lib/libclang.so.7 | grep SONAME
 0x0000000e (SONAME)                     Library soname: [libclang.so.7]
```

How can i avoid adding of ".7" in both filename and soname (to make it just `libclang.so`)?

I've tried to:

1) comment property like follows:

```
set_target_properties(libclang
  PROPERTIES
  #VERSION ${LIBCLANG_LIBRARY_VERSION}
  DEFINE_SYMBOL _CINDEX_LIB_)
```

and the filename and soname is still ".so.7" for some reason

2) set it empty:

```
set_target_properties(libclang
  PROPERTIES
  VERSION ""
  DEFINE_SYMBOL _CINDEX_LIB_)
```

and the filename and soname is ".so." (with dot at the end).

What can i do?

Comment: Numbers after `.so` are known as so-version, and CMake property responsible for it is [SOVERSION](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/SOVERSION.html). Note, that if this property is missed, but *VERSION* one exists, then *SOVERSION* is assumed to be the same as *VERSION*. You may try to set *SOVERSION* to empty string. Do not forget to remove old files before reconfiguring/rebuilding.

Comment: using `SOVERSION ""` generates "libclang.so." filename with no soname

Comment: Hm, so it effectively the same as *VERSION* setting. Actually, it looks strange that in the first scenario (without *VERSION* property at all) so-version `.7` is still created. What is an origin of that "7"...

Comment: You may try to use [set_property](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/command/set_property.html) command for clear the property (as opposite to setting the property to an empty string).

Comment: Yes, having ".7" (without explicit set) seems strange to me too. How can i clear the property with `set_property`? Could you please show an example. (i followed the link you've provided but i can't see how to _clear_ the property).

Comment: Hm, as far as I understand, `set_property(TARGET libclang PROPERTY VERSION)` should clear *VERSION* property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @Fred I was able to get it with the following (really dirty-dirty trick):

```
set_target_properties(libclang
  PROPERTIES
  #VERSION ${LIBCLANG_LIBRARY_VERSION}
  SUFFIX ""
  VERSION "so"
  SOVERSION "so"
  DEFINE_SYMBOL _CINDEX_LIB_)
```

I've checked it to have proper filename and soname:

```
~/llvm/build anton$ls -l lib/libclang.so
-rwxrwxr-x 1 anton anton 33590456 Nov 30 12:54 lib/libclang.so
~/llvm/build anton$arm-linux-androideabi-readelf --dynamic lib/libclang.so | grep SONAME
 0x0000000e (SONAME)                     Library soname: [libclang.so]
```

However i'm not sure if smth is wrong as i did not try to load it yet.

Please let me know if there is proper way to do it.

Comment: You are probably better off emailing the CMake mailing list then asking here.  I know that some of the CMake developers monitor the mailing list.

Comment: i did not think it's very specific issue and i expected some straight-forward solution that i'm just not aware of.

Answer (score 4):

I wasn't able to test this but try setting the NO_SONAME property instead of the other modifications.

```
set_target_properties(libclang
  PROPERTIES NO_SONAME 1
)
```

Comment: i still need soname, but equal to `libclang.so` (without `.7`). Using of `NO_SONAME 1` completely removes it.

Comment: removes what exactly?  so you end up with libclang and not libclang.so?  if you look at the target properties list you'll see that you can set outputname, suffix, version.  I had guessed that for shared libraries it was forming the name using (output_name).(suffix).(version).  You might want to use a combination of NO_SONAME and also setting suffix to ".so".

Comment: i end up with "libclang.so" filename with no soname. I need "libclang.so" with "libclang.so" soname.